# Sockets program with signal catcher

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make my server.c program be able to handle zombie processes. Originally, I found the line `signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN);` from [linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm.). This works like a charm. I can connect with a client then close the client and everything still runs smoothly.

However, I am trying to replace SIG_IGN with SigCatcher as written in the article and my server program starts going haywire when the client is closed(it infinitely keeps receiving "2" and outputs that).

I have tried both `wait3(NULL,WNOHANG,NULL)` as well as `wait(-1)` but neither of these solved the problem. What exactly should I be trying to do here?

```
void *SignalCatcher(int n)
{
  wait3(NULL,WNOHANG,NULL);
}
```

This is what my main looks like:

```
   //signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
   signal(SIGCHLD, SignalCatcher);

   for(;;)
   {
      clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
      connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);


      if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
      {
         close (listenfd);

         for(;;)
         {
            n = recvfrom(connfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&clilen);
            write(connfd , "" , 1);
            mesg[n] = 0;
            printf("Received the following:\n");
            printf("%s",mesg);

         }

      }
      close(connfd);
   }
```

Comment: You don't initialize the address length parameter for the `accept` and `recvfrom` calls. why are you using `recvfrom` for anyway? Your use of `accept` indicates you are using TCP, and then you can just use `recv` or even `read`.

Comment: You also should check for errors from the calls.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did initialize it, but just didn't include the whole body of the code. I figured this portion was enough. As for errors, I am not getting any; just getting a couple of warnings for bzero and wait3 for implicit declaration.

Comment: I don't mean compiler errors, but runtime errors from the function calls. You should always check the return value of functions calls that can return an error. What if the connection is closed, you don't have code to detect that?

Comment: I just added to the question to include this part about connection closing. When I had `SIG_IGN` as the second parameter for signal, I could close the client with no problems. However if I try to use a catcher/handler and then close my client, the server goes crazy. How should I go about tracing these runtime errors? I am not too familiar with this ubuntu environment. So far I only know that for some reason, even after the client is closed, recvfrom still keeps giving me mesg ='2'

Comment: In the for(;;) loop you should check the n==-1, and consult errno, and reloop on an interrupted system call. (the "2" is just the value that happens to be in the buffer from the previous call) BTW: you should handle the (n==0) case, too. Note `mesg[n] = 0;` writes beyond/before the buffer if n happens to be -1.

Comment: This n==-1 works, but how can I tell if my signal catcher is actually working? My server constantly spewing out numbers problem is fixed, but now I have a different situation. If I execute my server, then run my client and close it, nothing bad happens. However, if I proceed to run the client again and close it, I start getting defunct processes.

Comment: It sounds like your signal() function has System V semantics, i.e. requires reinstalling the handler after each received signal. I suggest using sigaction() to install the handler. Using signal() is very fragile and non-portable. If you insist on using signal() try defining -D_BSD_SOURCE or -D_GNU_SOURCE in your Makefile (assuming you are using Linux). What operating system and libc are you working with?

Comment: Im running on Ubuntu libc 2.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void *SignalCatcher(int n)
{
  wait3(NULL,WNOHANG,NULL);
}
```

Should be:

```
void SignalCatcher(int signum)
{
  wait3(NULL,WNOHANG,NULL);
}
```

The return type is *very* critical in a signal handler (because the calling convention is different from a normal function call). In any case, the compiler should *at least* have issued a warning.

Second: in the loop, you should handle error returns from recvfrom(). (and write() )

```
for(;;) {
        n = recvfrom(connfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&clilen);
        if (n == -1 && errno = EAGAIN) continue;
        else if (n == 0) break; // for non-blocking sockets...
        write(connfd , "" , 1);
        mesg[n] = 0;
        printf("Received the following: %s\n", mesg);
     }
```

Comment: Everything works but the errno == EAGAIN. I tried looking it up and sources pointed to EWOULDBLOCK, but both values bugged out my server having it infinitely repeat the last message sent. Either way, having only n==-1 works. Thanks

Comment: I also had to add the -1 condition for accept, but now everything works perfect. But I'm not too sure what do with errno.

Comment: There might be other errorconditions you want to ignore: resource busy/temporally unavailable etc. IMO Best to initially handle the expected ones, and log the unexpected ones. (and once they appear either ignore them, or fail gracefully). NB: EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother working so hard?  Just daemonize the children as soon as they start (eg, fork twice with the first child immediately exiting while the grand-child continues with pid 1 as its parent.)  Unless there is a reason to remain the parent of the worker processes, this will simplify things greatly.